# How to get Google Maps to show up at 100% in browser with reactjs?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I want to get Google Maps to show up in browser at full screen using reactjs.

My CSS:

```
html, body, #map_canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width:100%; height:100%;}
```

My component is defined as follows:

```
class GMap extends React.Component {
    render() {      
        return (<div className="GMap">
          <div ref="map_canvas" id="map_canvas">
          </div>
        </div>)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map_canvas = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.map_canvas);
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas,
            mapOptions);
    }
}
```

My problem is that nothing shows up. If I specify in the CSS a `width:500px` and `height:500px` or some arbitrary value, I can see it, but if I don't, I don't see anything. I want to replicate this in React:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map_canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, on this line: `<div ref="map_canvas" id="map_canvas">` Am I being redundant with ref and id?

I am using ES6, but am open to JSX solutions. I do not want to use any existing "react-google-map-library" for reasons that I want to simply use the existing library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `#map_canvas` to be 100% width and height of its parent, `GMap` which doesn't have a height or width defined as far as I can see.

If you create a fullscreen class, then you can just use it on both elements.

```
.fullscreen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /* extra fullscreen guarantees - you might not need the rest */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You can also remove the redundant `id` and switch to the more updated version of the `ref` syntax.

```
createMap(element) {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
}
render() {      
  return (
    <div className="fullscreen GMap">
      <div ref={this.createMap} className="fullscreen"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In response to your other question — yeah, you can change this stuff conditionally in your render function. In fact, you don't need CSS at all.

```
render() {
  const styles = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  };

  // you could also optionally use an alternate css class here.

  return (
    <div className="GMap">
      <div ref={this.createMap} style={styles}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, but it does not appear to show up (CSS). If I set the fullscreen class to have height and width in "px" instead of percentages, I see it show up.

Comment: Updated the CSS to be a bit more determined.

Comment: Is it redundant to have "fullscreen" in two places in this component? Or a better way to structure the dom for this? Also position:absolute looks a bit tricky, what if I wanted to use <GMap> in different contexts where I am not always wanting it to be fullscreen on a page?

Comment: It's only redundant if you are using the absolute positioning. 100% is a relative measure which uses the parents size. Either you can make sure that all the elements between `#map_canvas` and body have a width, or you can use the absolute approach.

Comment: May be a crazy question, but is there some "smarts" that can be coded into the render function to check for that and do things depending on situation?